# Adobe After effects file size

Tags: video, adobe, render, filesize, avi

Simple question, why exactly are rendered videos so huge?
I use Adobe After effects CS6
My raw footage is 4k at 60fps, and a 3 minute video is around 4 GB big.
So I used five of such videos, to make a one minute clip from them, rendered it to .avi at 1920*1080, 30fps and the file size went up to 9GB.
The only changes made to the videos is cutting together scenes and colour correction.

So why exactly are rendered videos from Adobe After Effects so incredibly huge, bigger than the raw material, although rendered at much lower quality, and what can I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you export an uncompressed avi, it will add more information than necessary by duplicating information from the original video. For best results, you should use a tiff or png sequence for the highest quality. If you want a video, use a mov wrapper and the DNxHR/DNxHD codec. This option will give you a video without sacrificing quality size or compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

> Please Use Adobe MediaEncoder to reduce your export file size with high quality video.

[image: Adobe Media Encoder]

Answer (score 0):

Like Toby Smith said, it is because of the raw format that the AVI codec uses. If you want to export good quality files at a small size cost, try using Adobe Media Encoder. You can import projects directly from After Effects and render them as .mp4, .mov, .avi, and several other file types. If you are in After Effects you can click File, then Export, and Export to Adobe Media Encoder in After Effects CC 2017, 2018, and 2019 (those are the ones I have used). You can then select the composition you want to render, and select the codec/settings you want to render it with.